# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Processing'

Tags: python, django

I'm going to deploy my django application on DigitalOcean. Everything gone well, except following error, and my question is: where can I find source of this error, actually in which file?

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, ccapp, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying ccapp.0009_auto_20191207_2148...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/progbash/ccproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1768, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Processing'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/progbash/ccproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/progbash/ccproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
...
  File "/home/progbash/ccproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2361, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/progbash/ccproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Processing'.
```

`models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class ApplicantStatus(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Applicant Statuses"
        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    motivation_letter = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ApplicantStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=3)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='static/applicant_photos', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Message(models.Model):
    message_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sender_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender_name
```

Comment: You likely are filtering with something like `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=bla)`, with `bla` a variable that now contains `Processing`. Probably the error is located in the view that is triggering the error.

Comment: Here is that part of my view:

```def index(request): 
    context = {
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
        'applicants':  Applicant.objects.filter(status=1),
        'empty_cards': range(4 - Applicant.objects.filter(status=1).count())
    }
```

Comment: is that the full traceback? i.e. is there anything else before the first `ValueError` line on the op?

Comment: @buran I just added the part before ```ValueError```

Comment: please post your models

Comment: @Exprator I did

Comment: are this all the models of the ccap app?

Comment: Please post your migration file (the one in ccapp/migrations whose name startswith "0009_auto_20191207_2148"). That's where the root problem is.

Comment: @Exprator we don't care about the models actually, the issue is in a migration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was in migration files. I just opened and changed default value from string type to integer.

Comment: From which migration files did you make the change?

Comment: I got **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'**

Comment: I solved the problem when using `get_or_create`, make sure to add `created` like this `my_model, created = myModel.objects.get_or_create(someForeignKeyField=someModel)`

Answer (score 15):

Just to share the solution that worked with my similar error that been received:
In my case, this same error was received because I was creating the model instant with the fields values directly, without specifying the field name, so always the ID was taking the first one as default (ID=field1).
The problem solved by adding the attributes name as well to the Instant creation.

Was:

```
model_instant = YourModel(field1, field2,...etc)
```

Solved by:

```
model_instant = YourModel(field1 = field1, field2 = field2,...etc)
```

Do this then follow what been recommended above of 1) deleting the dB file, and 2) delete the migrations then 3) do the makemigrations your_app_name then 4) migrations, then 5) run the server and you should be good to go.

Comment: I faced same problem. It was solved by passing  named arguments.

Answer (score 10):

Just delete all the migration files except the **init** python file the run python manage.py makemigrations then python manage.py migrate

Comment: don't do this if you already have data in your database.

Comment: This is not at all helpful to the question at hand without any context, please don't don't do the above

Comment: it is not the actual solution

Answer (score 7):

From the migration files, we can find the file starting with (001_initial.py,002_auto.py,003_,004_). In those files replace the default value empty string (default= '') or django.utils.timezone.now() into integer like (default=1). It might solve the problem.[image]

Comment: Please provide proper explanation like how above code would work

Answer (score 2):

*I was getting a similar error and finally found the cause. Just sharing here in case someone made a similar mistake.*

I had defined a custom `__init__` method on my model and had by mistake only written one `*` when passing kwargs to `super`:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().init(*args, *kwargs)
```

This resulted in the error message:

```bash
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'account'.
```

`account` was the first keyword argument I was passing when creating a new instance in a view.
In hindsight, the error message makes sense, but it took me an hour of confused debugging before I noticed my typo.

Comment: It took me 2 days to realize the same, so kudos for you for solving it in just 1 hour! :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I never added `created` to the `get_or_create`

```
someVariable = "someVariable"

# This will give the error "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got someVariable"

my_model = myModel.objects.get_or_create(someField=someVariable)
```

---

It got **solved** when adding this

```
# added created

my_model, created = myModel.objects.get_or_create(someField=someVariable)
```

See this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with simple CBV like TemplateView or ListView which does not require mandatory parameter. I'm pretty sure the issue comes from the url interpretation. For a simple ListView like

```
class ProfileList(generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
```

The url

```
path('profile_list/dummy', ProfileList.as_view(), name='profile_lv'),
```

works, whereas the one below, doesn't, the error: *Field 'id' expected a number but got 'profile_lv'* is thrown. Where *profile_lv* is the name of the url...

```
path('profile_list', ProfileList.as_view(), name='profile_lv'),
```

The addition of anything with a slash(/) after the path works?!...

Answer (score 0):

Just do nothing There are two ways :
1)Delete Your all migrations and type in your terminal:`python3 manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` then `python3 manage.py migrate` and then runserver.

2)Just opened and changed default value from string type to integer.

In my opinion choose first option because it is safe way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Delete your recentally created migrations file then run **python manage.py makemigrations** and **python manage.py migrate**. I think your problem going to solve.Please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to migration files and find the name id is where generate, then just replace id with processor or other name or remove it as it define as verbose_name.

```
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`
`python manage.py runserver`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was faced with this problem, but I was forced to create a new Django project from first, to solve this problem. And it was not solved by just deleting migrations files.

Answer (score 0):

I have confronted with similar type of error. My original URL was this one:

```
v1/unit/
```

Cleaning the migration files didn't help me. Fortunately, It just started to work after extending the URL with an additional string:

```
v1/unit/addProduct/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. `Clean up your dbase by deleting entries` which do not confirm to your model, `or putting in values for missing/wrong entries`
2. Make sure values in models are `blank=False, null=False` and `defaults given` and then rerun the migration
3. Put a condition such as if `Table.field != "":` or whatever value is causing problem in your serializers

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error below:

> TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Country: USA>.

Because `get_country()` returns an object to [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) instead of `id` as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_country(cls): # ↓ ↓ ↓ An object is returned ↓ ↓ ↓
        return Country.objects.get_or_create(id=1, name="USA")[0]

class Shipping(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, # ↓ An object is returned
        default=Country.get_country,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.country)
```

So, I returned `id` from `get_country()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "models.py"

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_country(cls):                                       # ↓ Here
        return Country.objects.get_or_create(id=1, name="USA")[0].id
```

Be careful, even if changing `self.name` to `str(self.id)` as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) # Here

    @classmethod
    def get_country(cls):
        return Country.objects.get_or_create(id=1, name="USA")[0]

# ...
```

Or, even if removing `__str__()` as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return str(self.id)

    @classmethod
    def get_country(cls):
        return Country.objects.get_or_create(id=1, name="USA")[0]

# ...
```

Then, the error was not solved.

Answer (score -3):

I solved it by deleting the `db`, `migrations` and `pycache` files then run `migrations` & `migrate` again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.