# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'r' - Django form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form that creates blog posts, however the form throws Exceptions when submitting. Strangely, however they still create these posts and  I can view these on the other page. Here are my models.py, views.py, form.py code and the stack trace.

Models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Author(models.Model):
    """ Inherits the auth user model """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Category(models.Model):
    """ Generic entries so posts can be filtered """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class News_Post(models.Model):
    """ Inherits Category & Author Models """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    post_img = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Forms.py:

```py
from .models import News_Post
from django import forms


class News_Post_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Form responsible for creating new posts. """
    id = None
    content = forms.CharField()
    categories = forms.CharField()
    featured = forms.BooleanField()
    post_img = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = News_Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'categories',
            'featured',
            'post_img',
        ]
```

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import News_Post, Author
from .forms import News_Post_Form
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.views.generic import CreateView


def get_author(user):
    """Gets the author"""
    ath= Author.objects.filter(user=user)
    if ath.exists():
        return ath[0]
    return None


class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    """Generic post view """
    model = News_Post
    template_name = 'create_post.html'
    form_class = News_Post_Form

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Create'
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = get_author(self.request.user)
        form.save()


@login_required
def news_post_create(request):
    """ Creates new posts """
    title = 'Create a new post.'
    author = get_author(request.user)
    form = News_Post_Form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = author
            form.clean()
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog/posts.html')
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'form': form,

    }
    return render(request, 'blog/create_post.html', context)


@login_required
def news_post(request):
    """ Renders the 'News_Post' model. """
    query = News_Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    context = {
        'obj_list': query
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/posts.html', context)
```

Didn't want to clog up the post with a sea of text, so for readability purposes I used Djangos stack trace sharing feature: [Stack trace](https://pastebin.com/5VuuFwKw)

I don't understand where the character 'r' is coming from, because it still updates the database, could someone also provide an explanation as to why this is occuring?  Also, I also tried following:
[ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Processing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266635/valueerror-field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-processing)

Comment: So it is populating Author with the correct ID?

Comment: @WombatPM Yes, the ID values all match up accordingly. They also render the relevant username to the actual template.

Comment: is it possible that it comes from a previous migration? maybe delete all migrations other than init.py and make migrations and migrate. Worked for me

Comment: No, I've removed these migrations and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I'm using the Materialize CSS framework, it overrides the default checkbox, and select HTML tags attributes so you need to initialize these with Javascript.
[Select - Materialize](https://materializecss.com/select.html)

So, I was force-ably trying to insert values into a Foreign Key value.